# Transform Text to jQuery Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm working with jQuery, Javascript and NodeJs ...

Currently I keep in my database as text jquery functions:

```
$('div.jail span').last().prev("span").text()
```

After I read from the database this text, I want to use it as jQuery function and not as a text.

I know it's a little silly, but because they can be many ways to get the result I want, so I keep it in a database.

Thanks!

Comment: It is an anti pattern usually but to use string as a command you need to use eval(yourText);

Comment: Thanks, I know it's antipattern but I can not think otherwise, any suggestions?

Comment: Keep the functions in the js and only save the params in db

Comment: Thanks. I was so in the beginning, but what I mean is that not everything is captured by last () or text (), if there are times I need to use html () or other functions to capture different values.

Comment: You need to re-think your architecture, if you need to save code in DB then something is wrong in your design

Comment: Keep the queries in separate functions in a config.js type file; query1 = function() { return $('div.jail span').last().prev("span").text(); }, query2 = ....... and so on

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
//use JSON.parse to get fn from json that you can save to db
var fn = {
  "selector": "div.jail span",
  "functions":[
    {"name": "last"},
    {"name": "prev", "param": "span"}
  ]
}

var el = $(fn.selector);

for(var i = 0; i < fn.functions.lenght; i++;){
  if(fn.functions[i].param) {
    el = el[fn.functions[i].name](fn.functions[i].param);
  } else {
    el = el[fn.functions[i].name]();
  }
}
```